# Proper way to use symbols as accessors

Tags: julia

What is the right way to wrap a Matrix and access using Symbols?

```
S = OhlcSeries{Float64}(100)
lastClose = S[:close, 0]

struct OhlcSeries{T} <: AbstractArray{T,2}
    data::Matrix{T}

    function OhlcSeries{T}(length::Int) where T
        data = Matrix{T}(4, length)
        new{T}(data)
    end
end

# Base.parent(A::OhlcSeries) = A.data
getindex(s::OhlcSeries,sym::Symbol) = getindex(s,Val{sym})
getindex(s::OhlcSeries,::Type{Val{:close}}) = view(s.data, 4, :)

# @inline function getindex(S::InputOhlcSeries, r::Symbol, col::Int)
#     @match r begin
#         :open => S.data[1, col]
#         :high => S.data[2, col]
#         :low  => S.data[3, col]
#         :close  => S.data[4, col]
#         _      => throw(ArgumentError("Expected one of :open, :high, :low, :close"))
#     end
# end

@inline function setindex!(S::InputOhlcSeries, value, r::Symbol, col::Int)
    @match r begin
        :open => S.data[1, col] = value
        :high => S.data[2, col] = value
        :low  => S.data[3, col] = value
        :close  => S.data[4, col] = value
        _      => throw(ArgumentError("Expected one of :open, :high, :low, :close"))
    end
end

@inline Base.getindex(S::OhlcSeries, i::Int, j::Int) = S.data[i, j]
@inline Base.setindex!(S::OhlcSeries, value, i::Int, j::Int) = S.data[i, j] = value
Base.size(S::OhlcSeries) = size(S.data.data)
Base.eltype(::Type{OhlcSeries{T}}) where {T} = T
Base.IndexStyle(::Type{<:OhlcSeries}) = IndexCartesian()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your type to be a subtype of `AbstratArray` you should minimally implement methods specified in the https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array-1 API specification. In particular you should decide on `IndexStyle` (looking at your structure `IndexLinear` should be efficient).

Then you can add custom indexing on top of it. Examples how this can be done are best looked-up in https://github.com/JuliaArrays/AxisArrays.jl package or https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl. I refer you to the sources as the code can get tricky, so it is best to inspect them in full.

If you prefer not to allow to index columns of your data structure by numbers but only by symbols, then this is also fully doable, but this type will not support `AbstractArray` API, so if you pass it to standard library functions that assume this API is fulfilled you can get errors.